# how to make one part of a flex div not follow align-items center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I got a navbar, and whilst working on mobile responsiveness when I open the mobile menu, the logo moves down with the list towards the center. How can I prevent this, I want the logo to remain in its original place and not move when I open up the list??? It also moves to the left which I'm also not sure what to do about because I set the property to justify-content: space-around;.

```js
function mobileNav() {
  let navlinks = document.getElementById('myLinks');
  let section1 = document.getElementById("section1");
  if (navlinks.style.display == 'none') {
      navlinks.style.display = 'block';
      section1.style.height = '70vh';
  } else {
      section1.style.height = '50vh'
      navlinks.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.navbar {
    /* max-width: 100%; */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content:  space-around;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
}

.logo {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}

.nav-options i {
    color: white;
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    .nav-options i {
        display: block;
        font-size: 3rem;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #myLinks {
        display: none;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .nav-options #myLinks a {
        display: block;
        text-align: right;
        padding: 5px 0px;
    }
}

/* ADDED otherwise it is white on white */
body{
  background:salmon;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="navbar">
  <label class="logo" id="logo">COINGAIN</label>
  <div class="nav-options">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="mobileNav()" id="hamburger"></i>
    <div id="myLinks">
      <a href="coingain.html">Home</a>
      <a href="aboutcoingain.html">About</a>
      <a href="#">App</a>
      <a href="coingainfeatures.html">Features</a>
      <button class="start" id="">Get Started</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to **position the `#myLinks` div *absolutely*** so that it does not affect the flow of the other items in the flexbox (and the page). For this to work, you also need to position its parent the `.nav-options` div relatively, like so:

1. **Position the `.nav-options` div relatively**.

   ```
   .nav-options {
       position: relative;
    }
   ```
2. **Then position the `#myLinks` div (the dropdown div) absolutely within its parent div `.nav-options`** and give it a right positioning of 0px (or 0rem or just 0).

   ```
   #myLinks {
       ...
       position: absolute;
       right: 0px;
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: this causes a button I put below the navbar not to be moved down, should I force it down with more padding?

Comment: Please, for clarification, is the button part of the navbar or the rest of the page? 

By setting position to absolute, it means that the placement of the dropdown will not affect the flow of the rest of the page. It would be as though it was never on the page as far as other differently positioned elements are concerned, so they won't get shifted. If you need the button to be visible when the dropdown is open, consider placing it elsewhere on the page like at the center or left side of the page where it won't be obstructed by the dropdown, or making it part of the dropdown menu.

Comment: The button is a part of the rest of the page.

Comment: Okay, consider placing it in a different part of the page where the dropdown menu doesn't get in its way. The other less ideal solution I can think of would be to assign relative position to the '#myLinks' div but this would affect the logo. To prevent that, you would then need to assign absolute position to the logo element and set top and left values to prevent it from shifting. If you need clarification, let me know so that I may edit my answer to include this workaround.

Comment: thanks man! :) worked it out eventually

Comment: Wonderful! Glad you found a solution to your problem. :)